# Excel VBA using Selenium - click on list element to change focus

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scape data from a website via Excel VBA. I have a web page which has different data depending on a button selection, but the button sits withing a ul list. I can find the element by class using:

.FindElementByClass("shared-filter-button-list_navItem__ZiG2J")

But I can seem to work out how to switch the focus between 'This season' and 'All time' to change to displayed data on the page. Any ideas would be gratefully received. The html is:

```html
<ul class="shared-filter-button-list_navContainer__3hJmS"><li class="shared-filter-button-list_navItem__ZiG2J is-active"><button class="tag-button_btn__1B2dI tag-button__purple__3SyTF shared-filter-button_wrap__3OgbA  is-active" value="This season" type="button">This season</button></li><li class="shared-filter-button-list_navItem__ZiG2J"><button class="tag-button_btn__1B2dI tag-button__purple__3SyTF shared-filter-button_wrap__3OgbA  " value="All time" type="button">All time</button></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see the page, but if you just want to click the "this season" or "all time" button, just find the buttons inside the list you already have and click one?

**update**
I misread the provided HTML (its all in one line) and thought that `shared-filter-button-list_navItem__ZiG2J` was the container `ul` not the list items, and also that selenium uses 1-based indexes not 0-based.

The code below finds all buttons that match the query and prints their index and text to the debug window.

```
Private Driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Main()
Set Driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Driver.Get "https://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/eurocup/players/lukas-meisner/011187/"

Dim List As Selenium.WebElements
' get a list of button that are children of li with specified class name
Set List = Driver.FindElementsByXPath("//li[contains(@class, 'shared-filter-button-list_navItem__ZiG2J')]/button", 0, 5000)

If List Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "failed to get list"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Index = 1 To List.Count
    Debug.Print Index & " -> " & List(Index).Text
Next Index

End Sub
```

Expected result from this code is:

```
1 -> This season
2 -> All time
3 -> Regular Season
```

If you wanted to click the *This season* button

```
List(1).Click
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, that gives me an 'Index is outside the bounds of the array' error. An example of the page is: https://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/eurocup/players/lukas-meisner/011187/

Comment: Nick that is perfect, List(1).Click and List(2).Click do exactly what I was after!! Many thanks